# Jquery + Firebase: How to connect date to status posts?

Tags: jquery, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a website for university that has a status update that people add to. When posted, the word or sentence gets sent to my Firebase Realtime Database account where it is then stored.

I am wanting to add some things to the jquery, however I'm not that good at jquery - I don't understand it very well.

Is there a way to add the date, so that each time a post is made the date is added at the bottom - to signify when it was added.

Here's my firebase jquery code:

```
<script>
// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
apiKey: "AIzaSyBcVJsd1tQqEFKeWZ5VD1AMh79BfDnNlyk",
authDomain: "project-3-7caba.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://project-3-7caba.firebaseio.com",
storageBucket: "project-3-7caba.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "595847032866"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

var database = firebase.database();

function saveData(){
var userInputText = $('#userText').val();

database.ref('/').push({
hello: userInputText,
color: '#333333'
});
}


database.ref('/').on('value', function(snapshot) {
$('#timeline').empty();

var data = snapshot.val();
console.log(data);

$.each(data, function( index, value ) {
console.log(value.hello);
$( "#timeline" ).prepend( "<p>" + value.hello + "</p>" );
$("#userText").val('');
});

});
</script>
```

I have been looking at Livestamp by Matt Bradley

Answer (score 0):

writing:

add a `date` to your data, like so:

```
database.ref('/').push({
hello: userInputText,
color: '#333333',
date: new Date()
});
```

reading:

```
  database.ref('/').on('value', function(snapshot) {
  var data = snapshot.val();
  $.each(data, function( index, value ) {

    // do something with: value.date

  });

  });
```

Comment: when you iterate `data`, the current entry's data (like the date, color or 'hello' properties) would be accessible via dot notation on the `value` variable.

Comment: i'm sorry, i just don't understand how to make it work... like, do i need to write up code for the value.date or?? and with your 'reading' section, do i need to remove the parts of my code that you did?

Comment: `new Date()` in JS gives you a new date, so i assigned that to a property called `date` and added it to the rest of the properties in the `push` function. now the entry will have a key for each property - date, along with a color and a text input. when you loop through the data you got from firebase, you can read the values of those  keys using dot notation, like in the example.